# Nonnegative least squares relation to unconstrained least squares

Tags: statistics, least-squares

I have a dataset that I was originally doing a standard (unconstrained) least squares fit on.  I wanted to change to a constrained least squares fit, where I want only nonnegative parameters.  I'm currently using MATLAB's function 'lsqnonneg' to solve a nonnegative least squares problem, which is working just fine.  I've noticed that for all the cases where I used to have a negative parameter, that parameter has simply become zero.  Although I don't know what MATLAB's function is doing under the hood, from the examples I've done so far, it looks like I could just do a standard least squares fit, set any negative parameters to zero, and then redo my fit with the remaining parameters using the standard method again.  Will this always be the case -- that negative parameters in the unconstrained case will just be zero in the nonnegative constrained case?  I haven't found any mention of this in the sources I've looked at but can't manage to cook up a counterexample where this doesn't happen.  Either an explanation of why this must happen or a counterexample would be really helpful!

Comment: Since least-squares fitting amounts to minimizing an error function, here's a simple one: minimize $(x-1)^2+1000(x+y)^2$. This corresponds to the two equations $x=1$ and $1000x+1000y=0$. The unconstrained minimum is $(x=1,y=-1)$, but in the nonnegative case $(x=0,y=0)$ is better than $(x=1,y=0)$.

Comment: I don't think this is a counterexample to what I'm describing.  This still involves setting the formerly negative parameter (y) to zero and then redoing the fit.  (This might result in other parameters changing, possibly even to zero.) I'm wondering if there is a case in which the unconstrained case would give y<0 and the constrained case would give y>0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that if a variable is negative in the solution to unconstrained least-squares problem, then it will be zero in the solution to the nonnegatively constrained version of the same problem. Here is a counterexample:

$$\begin{align}
y+1 &= 0, \\
1000(2x-y+1) &= 0.
\end{align}$$

The unconstrained solution is $x=-1, y=-1$. The nonnegatively constrained solution is close to $x=0, y=1$; the sign of $y$ is different.